# Symfony, security.yml "Unknown Entity namespace alias"

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I would like to implement Symfony security into my project. Problem is I have to use two databases (one for admins, second for users). I have configured config.yml :

```
orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: %kernel.debug%
        default_entity_manager: default
        entity_managers:
            default:
                connection: system
                mappings:
                    FinanceCmsBundle:  ~
            admin:
                connection: admin
                mappings:
                    FinanceCzBundle:  ~
```

and set my security.yml :

```
security:
    encoders:
        Finance\CmsBundle\Entity\AuthUser:
            algorithm: md5
            encode_as_base64: false
            iterations: 0
        Finance\CzBundle\Entity\SystemAuthMailCentrum:
            algorithm: md5
            encode_as_base64: false
            iterations: 0

    providers:
        administrators:
            entity:
                class: FinanceCmsBundle:AuthUser
                property: username
        ussers:
            entity:
                class: FinanceCzBundle:SystemAuthMailCentrum
                property: username
```

Before I started I tested it on a copy of a table on a database under FinanceCmsBundle:SystemAuthMailCentrum and it worked correctly.

Now aplication ends with "Doctrine\ORM\ORMException

`Unknown Entity namespace alias 'FinanceCzBundle'"`

I have tried to switch them  (FinanceCzBundle with FinanceCmsBundle) in config.yml and it looks like the aplication knows only the default Bundle set in config.yml. Because after this switch it does not find FinanceCmsBundle.

So I have tried to use full routes like:

```
 providers:
        administrators:
            entity:
                class: Finance\CmsBundle\Entity\AuthUser
                property: username
        ussers:
            entity:
                class: Finance\CzBundle\Entity\SystemAuthMailCentrum
                property: username
```

After that I get different errors: `"Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException`

`The class 'Finance\CzBundle\Entity\SystemAuthMailCentrum' was not found in the chain configured namespaces Finance\CmsBundle\Entity"`

Thanks a lot for any answer.

P.S : It would be easier to use one database, but the code is old and I would have to fix it on many places.

Comment: In your routes, there seems to be a typo ('ussers' instead of 'users')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set the entity manager to providers, I think it should help:

```
providers:
    administrators:
        entity:
            class: FinanceCmsBundle:AuthUser
            property: username
    ussers:
        entity:
            class: FinanceCzBundle:SystemAuthMailCentrum
            property: username
            manager_name: admin
```